# Как принимать только целочисленные числа aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Вот код

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InputFile
import re
import pygsheets
from states import Form

path=''
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=path)
sh = gc.open('pythontest')
wks = sh[0]
bot = Bot(token='')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

data = []


Estimilated_UK_sizes = {
0: "AA",
1: "A",
2: "B",
3: "C",
4: "D",
5: "DD",
6: "E",
7: "F",
8: "FF",
9: "G",
10: "GG",
11: "H",
12: "HH",
13: "J",
14: "JJ",
15: "K",
16: "KK",
17: "L",
18: "LL",
19: "M",
20: "MM",
21: "N",
24: "OO",
}

@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    data.clear()
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_1 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Запустить")
    keyboard.add(button_1)
    await message.answer("Добро пожаловать на онлайн \n Я виртуальный помощник  от  \n Жми «запустить» и мы начнем", reply_markup=keyboard)
    await Form.name.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Запустить", state=Form.name)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Как я могу к тебе обращаться?")
    await Form.age.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):  
    data.append(message.text)
    await message.answer(f"Отлично, {message.text} подскажи пожалуйста, сколько тебе лет?")
    await Form.F.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.F)
async def process_F(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data.append(message.text)
    await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
    await Form.Forma.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Forma)
async def process_Forma(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data.append(message.text)  
    await message.answer(f"Превосходно! Давай перейдем к твоей ____ выбери свою форму___(от 1-12))")
    await Form.Position.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Position)
async def process_surname(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data.append(message.text)  
    await message.answer(f"Выбери расположение……..\n(Фото с выбором 1 или 2)")
    await Form.OPGinhale.set()
    
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OPGinhale)
async def process_OPGinhale(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data.append(message.text)
    await message.answer("Супер! До консультации и подарочной скидки 20% на остался последний шаг")
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОПГ вдох")
    await Form.OPGouthale.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OPGouthale)
async def process_OPGouthale(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data.append(message.text)
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОПГ выдох")
    await Form.OG.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OG)
async def process_OG(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОГ")
    data.append(message.text)
    await Form.end.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.end)
async def process_end(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Спасибо за ответы!")    
    data.append(message.text)
    print(data)
    FirstFormula = int(data[5]) - 8
    SecondFormula = (int(data[7]) - int(data[5])) / 2.54
    SecondFormula = int(SecondFormula)
    print(FirstFormula, SecondFormula)
    if SecondFormula in Estimilated_UK_sizes:
        size = Estimilated_UK_sizes[SecondFormula]
        data.append(str(FirstFormula) + size)
    
    data.append(message.from_user.id)
    data.append(message.from_user.full_name)

    print(data)

    wks.append_table(data, start='A2', end=None, 
                     dimension='ROWS', overwrite=False)
    await state.finish()

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Некоторые хэндлеры должны принимать только числа и если это не число то бот отправляет сообщение по типу "Введите только числами".
Пишу потому что не получается.

UPD.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.F)
async def process_F(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # data.append(message.text)
    # await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
    # await Form.Forma.set()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['F'] = message.text
    if data['F'].isdigit():
        await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
        await Form.Forma.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('введи целое положительное число')
```

Ответ бота
[13.07.2023 23:36]
Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)

Рамиль, [13.07.2023 23:36]
ы

[13.07.2023 23:36]
Превосходно! Давай перейдем к твоей ____ выбери свою форму___(от 1-12))

UPD2.
Вот код

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InputFile
import re
import pygsheets
from states import Form

path='studious-rhythm-390907-798ae3194f44.json'
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=path)
sh = gc.open('pythontest')
wks = sh[0]
bot = Bot(token='')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

data = []


Estimilated_UK_sizes = {
    0: "AA",
    1: "A",
    2: "B",
    3: "C",
    4: "D",
    5: "DD",
    6: "E",
    7: "F",
    8: "FF",
    9: "G",
    10: "GG",
    11: "H",
    12: "HH",
    13: "J",
    14: "JJ",
    15: "K",
    16: "KK",
    17: "L",
    18: "LL",
    19: "M",
    20: "MM",
    21: "N",
    24: "OO",
}


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_1 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Запустить")
    keyboard.add(button_1)
    await message.answer("Добро пожаловать на онлайн \n Я виртуальный помощник  от  \n Жми «запустить» и мы начнем", reply_markup=keyboard)
    await Form.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Запустить", state=Form.name)
async def process_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Как я могу к тебе обращаться?")
    await Form.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.name)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Отлично, {message.text}, подскажи пожалуйста, сколько тебе лет?")
    await Form.age.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['age'] = message.text
    if data['age'].isdigit():
        await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
        await Form.F.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('введи целое положительное число')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.F)
async def process_f(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['f'] = message.text
    if data['f'].isdigit() and 1 <= int(data['f']) <= 6:
        await message.answer(f"Превосходно! Давай перейдем к твоей ____ выбери свою форму___(от 1-12)")
        await Form.Position.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('введи число от 1 до 6')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Position)
async def process_position(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Forma'] = message.text
    if data['Forma'].isdigit() and 1 <= int(data['Forma']) <= 12:
        await message.answer(f"Выбери расположение……..\n(Фото с выбором 1 или 2)")
        await Form.OPGinhale.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('введи число от 1 до 12')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OPGinhale)
async def process_OPGinhale(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Position'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Супер! До консультации и подарочной скидки 20% на остался последний шаг")
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОПГ вдох")
    await Form.OPGouthale.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OPGouthale)
async def process_OPGouthale(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['OPGinhale'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОПГ выдох")
    await Form.OG.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OG)
async def process_OG(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['OPGouthale'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОГ")
    await Form.end.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.end)
async def process_end(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['OG'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Спасибо за ответы!")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        FirstFormula = int(data['OPGinhale']) - 8
        SecondFormula = (int(data['OG']) - int(data['OPGinhale'])) / 2.54
        SecondFormula = int(SecondFormula)
        print(FirstFormula, SecondFormula)
        if SecondFormula in Estimilated_UK_sizes:
            size = Estimilated_UK_sizes[SecondFormula]
            data["Formula"] = (str(FirstFormula) + size)

        data["ID"] = message.from_user.id
        data["UserName"] = message.from_user.full_name

        print(data)

        wks.append_table(data, start='A2', end=None,
                         dimension='ROWS', overwrite=False)
        await state.finish()
```

Вот ошибка

```
85 3
FSMContextProxy state = 'Form:end', data = {'name': 'asd', 'age': '12', 'f': '1', 'Forma': '2', 'Position': '3', 'OPGinhale': '93', 'OPGouthale': '89', 'OG': '101', 'Formula': '85C', 'ID': 1915805542, 'UserName': 'Рамиль'}
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-47' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=KeyError(0)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\main.py", line 148, in process_end
    wks.append_table(data, start='A2', end=None,
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\utils.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\worksheet.py", line 1138, in append_table
    if type(values[0]) != list:
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\Order\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\storage.py", line 439, in __getitem__
    return self._data[item]
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
class Form(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    age = State()
    f = State()
    position = State()
    OPGinhale = State()
    OPGouthale = State()
    OG = State()
    end = State()


Estimilated_UK_sizes = {
    0: "AA",
    1: "A",
    2: "B",
    3: "C",
    4: "D",
    5: "DD",
    6: "E",
    7: "F",
    8: "FF",
    9: "G",
    10: "GG",
    11: "H",
    12: "HH",
    13: "J",
    14: "JJ",
    15: "K",
    16: "KK",
    17: "L",
    18: "LL",
    19: "M",
    20: "MM",
    21: "N",
    24: "OO",
}


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_1 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Запустить")
    keyboard.add(button_1)
    await message.answer("Добро пожаловать на онлайн \n Я виртуальный помощник  от  \n Жми «запустить» и мы начнем", reply_markup=keyboard)
    await Form.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Запустить", state=Form.name)
async def process_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Как я могу к тебе обращаться?")
    await Form.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.name)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Отлично, {message.text}, подскажи пожалуйста, сколько тебе лет?")
    await Form.age.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['age'] = message.text
    if data['age'].isdigit():
        await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
        await Form.f.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('введи целое положительное число')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.f)
async def process_f(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['f'] = message.text
    if data['f'].isdigit() and 1 <= int(data['f']) <= 6:
        await message.answer(f"Превосходно! Давай перейдем к твоей ____ выбери свою форму___(от 1-12)")
        await Form.position.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('введи число от 1 до 6')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.position)
async def process_position(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['position'] = message.text
    if data['position'].isdigit() and 1 <= int(data['position']) <= 12:
        await message.answer(f"Выбери расположение……..\n(Фото с выбором 1 или 2)")
        await Form.OPGinhale.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('введи число от 1 до 12')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OPGinhale)
async def process_OPGinhale(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['OPGinhale'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Супер! До консультации и подарочной скидки 20% на остался последний шаг")
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОПГ вдох")
    await Form.OPGouthale.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OPGouthale)
async def process_OPGouthale(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['OPGouthale'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОПГ выдох")
    await Form.OG.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.OG)
async def process_OG(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['OG'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Сделай замеры ОГ")
    await Form.end.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.end)
async def process_end(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Спасибо за ответы!")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        FirstFormula = int(data['OPGinhale']) - 8
        SecondFormula = (int(data['OG']) - int(data['OPGinhale'])) / 2.54
        SecondFormula = int(SecondFormula)
        print(FirstFormula, SecondFormula)
        if SecondFormula in Estimilated_UK_sizes:
            size = Estimilated_UK_sizes[SecondFormula]
            data.append(str(FirstFormula) + size)

        data.append(message.from_user.id)
        data.append(message.from_user.full_name)

        print(data)

        wks.append_table(data, start='A2', end=None,
                         dimension='ROWS', overwrite=False)
        await state.finish()
```

### UPD

По поводу добавления данных в таблицу, могу предложить библиотеку `gspread`, в ней, как по мне, проще работать:

```
import gspread

service_account = gspread.service_account(filename='service_account.json') # Укажите путь к файлу JSON сервисного аккаунта
gs = service_account.open("SPREADSHEET NAME") # Тут название гугл таблицы
list_name = "LIST NAME" # Тут название листа
```

а дальше последний хэндлер измените так:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.end)
async def process_end(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['OG'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Спасибо за ответы!")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        FirstFormula = int(data['OPGinhale']) - 8
        SecondFormula = (int(data['OG']) - int(data['OPGinhale'])) / 2.54
        SecondFormula = int(SecondFormula)
        print(FirstFormula, SecondFormula)
        if SecondFormula in Estimilated_UK_sizes:
            size = Estimilated_UK_sizes[SecondFormula]
            data["Formula"] = (str(FirstFormula) + size)

        data["ID"] = message.from_user.id
        data["UserName"] = message.from_user.full_name

        x = [[i for i in data.values()]]
        gs.values_append(list_name, {'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, {'values': x})
        await state.finish()
```

Comment: Рамиль, [13.07.2023 20:36]
Запустить

 [13.07.2023 20:36]
Как я могу к тебе обращаться?

 [13.07.2023 20:36]
введи целое положительное число

Рамиль, [13.07.2023 20:36]
фыв

Сразу кидает else. не то

Comment: @Zemmeus я дополнил ответ, обратите внимание как необходимо исправить ваш остальной код

Comment: Не работает( 
Смотри в вопросе

Comment: @Zemmeus значит где-то что то напутали )) добавил полный код, пробуйте, правда не уверен, что корректно делаются расчеты в самом конце, подставьте нужное. Но там, на сколько я понимаю вашу задумку, в остальных хэндлерах тоже должна быть проверка ввода. Ну и на заметку - плохая практика называть переменные с большой буквы

Comment: @Zemmeus и да, идея с использованием `data.append(message.text)` плохая, потому что если боту будут писать одновременно 2 и более человека, то ответы каждого из них будут добавляться в список и неизвестно какие расчеты в итоге будут производиться в самом конце для каждого ))

Comment: Спасибо большое тебе. Не понял чем отличаются наши коды? я вроде тоже так пробовал но сравнивал переменную с числом а не список.  Еще чек пж вопрос там еще одна ошибка(

Comment: что то с добавлением в таблицу

Comment: @Zemmeus проверяйте, код разросся и тема вместе с ним )) по этому если djpybrywn новые вопросы, то лучше создавайте новую тему

Comment: все спасибо починил. забыл что нужно вытаскивать значения из словаря)

Comment: Кстати. await state.finish() не работает почему то(  Спасибо за ответы выдает и вписывает еще раз в таблицу

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.F)
async def process_F(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data.append(message.text)
    await message.answer(f"Выбери свой тип Ф___ и напиши ответ цифрой (от 1-6)")
    await Form.Forma.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Forma)
async def process_Forma(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if not message.text.isdigit():
        await message.answer(f"{message.text} - не является числом! Введи ещё раз!")
        await Form.f.set()
        return

    data.append(message.text)  
    await message.answer(f"Превосходно! Давай перейдем к твоей ____ выбери свою форму___(от 1-12))")
    await Form.Position.set()
```